# Extract result using AWK command

Tags: linux, unix, awk

With this command :

```
cat access.log | grep file | grep xx.xx.xx.xx | awk -F "-" '{print $3}' | awk -F "[" '{print $2}' | awk -F "]" '{print $1}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}'
```

I obtain this result :

```
10/Nov/2015:17:38:47
```

I need to have in output the result formatted like this :

```
10/Nov/2015:17
```

I try adding this :

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1,":",$2}'
```

But i obtain :

```
10/Nov/2015 : 17
```

How can i obtain the result without that blank? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you give a sample of the log file? Does it have to be `awk`? Multiple chained `awk` pipes seems wrong.

Comment: Looks like you should learn how to maintain regular expressions. 2 times grep and 5 times(!!) awk in *one* pipe it far too heavy!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the commas, so awk doesn't insert the `OFS` (a space by default) between each field:

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1":"$2}'
```

Though it'd be more idiomatic to set the `OFS` yourself:

```
awk -F ":" -v OFS=":" '{print $1,$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this a horrible way - chaining multiple greps and awks is almost certainly redundant.

I'm going to take a bit of a guess that you're looking at a `httpd` access log looking like this: (from: http://www.monitorware.com/en/logsamples/apache.php)

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:06:51 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/rdiff/TWiki/NewUserTemplate?rev1=1.3&rev2=1.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4523
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:10:02 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/hsdivision HTTP/1.1" 200 6291
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:11:58 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/WikiSyntax HTTP/1.1" 200 7352
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:20:55 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/DCCAndPostFix HTTP/1.1" 200 5253
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:23:12 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/oops/TWiki/AppendixFileSystem?template=oopsmore¶m1=1.12¶m2=1.12 HTTP/1.1" 200 11382
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:24:16 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/PeterThoeny HTTP/1.1" 200 4924
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:29:16 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Header_checks?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12851
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:30:29 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/attach/Main/OfficeLocations HTTP/1.1" 401 12851
```

To get what you want out of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
    if ( m/64.242.88.10/
     and m/TWiki/ )       { 
        my ($date, $tz) = m/\[(\S+):\d{2}:\d{2} ([-+\d]+)\]/;
        print $date,"\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
07/Mar/2004:16
07/Mar/2004:16
07/Mar/2004:16
```

This can be one-liner-ified thus:

```
perl -lne 'if (m/64.242.88.10/ and m/TWiki/ and m/\[(\S+):\d{2}:\d{2} / ) { print $1 }' access.log
```

Or as noted by [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman):

```
perl -lne '/64.242.88.10/ && /TWiki/ && /\[(\S+):\d{2}:\d{2} / && print $1' access.log
```

Comment: If you're matching numeric time zone offets, you might get some with `+0300`, so your match might be `[+-]\d+`

Comment: Your one-liner can be golfed a bit without loss of readability, I think: `perl -lne '/64.242.88.10/ && /TWiki/ && /\[(\S+):\d{2}:\d{2} / && print $1' access.log`

Answer (score 0):

Using the same log file @Sobrique's answer you can try this simpler script

```
awk '/^64.242.88.10/ && /twiki/ {print $4}' access.log | cut -c2-15
```

assuming you're interested in a specific ip and keyword=twiki (file in your example)